# Update a variable number of rows each with different values in a single SQL command?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of ordered data like this

```
ID   ORDER
12     1
13     2
14     3
15     4
...
200    189
201    190
...
```

I would like to be able to update a few or all of their "order"s. 
How should I do that?

For example, I might switch the ordering between ID=12 and ID=13 so it'd go like

```
ID   ORDER
12     2
13     1
14     3
15     4
...
```

This would just be a simple `UPDATE TABLE SET ORDER=1 WHERE ID=13 SET ORDER=2 WHERE ID=12`

But if I wanted to move ID=200 all the way to the top,..

```
ID   ORDER
12     2
13     3
14     4
15     5
...
200    190
201    1
...
```

then everything would have to be updated..? How do I do that? Is there a better way? Decimals?

edit: I'm using MSSQL btw

edit:clarification of use:  I have a table with a long list of URL links, and the order of those links matter. I want to be able to rearrange their order. I have a web page that retrieves that list from the db, displays the names as an unordered-list, and I can rearrange the items on that list. I'm stuck on how to get the newly ordered list's order updated into the database.

Comment: What you would like to be able to  ?? Your question is not clear ?

Comment: Are you sure you need it that way, it's not a good desing decision. And if answer is yes - specify the Sql server are you using, your task can't be done in universal way.

Comment: Yeah I figure this isn't be best way of doing it. I just need a data list that can be reordered, but can't find a good alternative. I'm having a hard time thinking up good keywords for google. I'm using MSSQL.

Comment: Wouldn't the second case just be `UPDATE Table SET Order = (CASE WHEN ID=201 THEN 1 ELSE Order+1 END) WHERE Order >= 1 AND Order <= 190`?

Comment: Ah, I actually didn't know about CASE's (SQL noob) but that seems like it would work! Could I mark a comment as the answer?

Comment: @CheapSteaks: No, you can't mark a comment as the solution, which is why I've added it as an answer below. Also, if you'd like me to receive a notification when you respond to my comment, you have to start it with 'at'-username (like I did). Otherwise I have to manually check back to see if anyone responded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to move an item up to the top, and update the order of all the other in a single statment, you can do the following:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET    Order = (CASE Order WHEN 190 THEN 1
                           ELSE Order + 1
                           END)
WHERE  Order BETWEEN 1 AND 190
```

Comment: I think this is by far the simplest answer to the needs of the OP.

Answer (score 3):

To move Id 200 to the top, you have to do this:

1) Take everything which is ordered before Id 200 and increase the order by 1

```
update MyTable 
set Order = Order + 1 
where Order < (select Order from MyTable where Id = 200)
```

2) Put Id 200 to the top of the list (Order = 1)

```
update MyTable 
set Order = 1
where Id = 200
```

Comment: This works, but only if there are no unique constraints on the "Order" column.

Comment: I would implement this method with one exception, create a temp table with the new sort order as an intermediate step. Then destroy the original table and replace it with the values from the temp table.

Answer (score 1):

I think, What you are looking is

```
Select * from TableName order by ID Desc/Asc
```

You want to Order the rows, `Ascending` or `Descending`

Comment: I accidentally pressed enter when typing the question, please take another look at it. I'm not trying to SELECT data, I'm trying to update a variable amount of entries, each to a different value

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the above question quite answers it.  I believe the answer to your question is what you already suspect - to change order = 200 to order = 1, you will have to rescore every other value, or use a number format with decimals.

However, I strongly suspect that if you elaborated more on why you need to do it this way, we could chime in with some better recommended methods.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have a table with a long list of URL links, and the order of those links matter. I want to be able to rearrange their order. I have a web page that retrieves that list from the db, displays the names as an unordered-list, and I can rearrange the items on that list. I'm stuck on how to get the newly ordered list's order updated into the database. I probably will have to just send back a long string of all the ID+ORDER pairs :(

Comment: @CheapSteaks - Please edit your questions and add your abouve comment as a clarification.

Comment: @CheapSteaks: Don't send a string containing a sequence of structured data that requires deciphering on the server side. Use a [Table-valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) instead. It's both fast and convenient.

Comment: @Allon Guralnek I'm not entirely able to comprehend that page :( Am I passing the entire table to it?

Comment: @CheapSteaks: Yes, you pass an entire table as one of the parameters. You can then use it inside a sproc as if it's just any table (e.g. join it with an actual table). It is the same as table variable, only it can be sent from the client. It is _the_ way to send structured data to sprocs.

Comment: @Allon Guralnek  That is amazing..would save so much time